# Saving a list of parent objects and their children (that have foreign keys of parent) all at the same time with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Will the below code automatically save the Sales Orders to the SalesOrder table and the Sales Order Details to the SalesOrderDetail table?

My goal is to be able to create a list of my primary entitity and use it's navigation property to create another list and save it all in one shot.

Please see below:

```
List<SalesOrder> salesOrders = new List<SalesOrder>()
{
    new SalesOrder()
    {
        OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
        OrderDetails = new List<SalesOrderDetail>()
        {
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 1 },
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 2 },
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 3 }
        }
    },
    new SalesOrder()
    {
        OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
        OrderDetails = new List<SalesOrderDetail>()
        {
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 1 },
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 2 }
        }
    }
};

_context.SalesOrders.AddRange(salesOrders);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

or am I going to have to do something like:

```
_context.SalesOrders.AddRange(salesOrders);
_context.SalesOrderDetails.AddRange(salesOrders[0].OrderDetails);
_context.SalesOrderDetails.AddRange(salesOrders[1].OrderDetails);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Run the code and see if it works?

Comment: @ZivWeissman's advice is best.  Experiment!  However, from an armchair (thinking-about-it-without-running-the-experiment) perspective.  I don't see why this would work.  EF uses properties to link entities, the EF equivalent of SQL join conditions.  Neither your SalesOrders nor your SalesOrderDetails have been given the information need to link to their related entities.  I'll post an example as an answer showing how EF actually knows to link two entities.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Entity Framework Core 1.0 (EF7) and the following worked perfectly. Please take note at how my models are setup:

```
    public class SalesOrder 
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}
        // Nav property
        public ICollection<SalesOrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class SalesOrderDetail
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        // Foreign key property
        public int SalesOrderId {get; set;}
        // Nav property
        public SalesOrder SalesOrder {get; set;}
    }
```

Simply doing the following works and automatically saves the correct foreign key values without me having to specify them:

```
List<SalesOrder> salesOrders = new List<SalesOrder>()
{
    new SalesOrder()
    {
        OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
        OrderDetails = new List<SalesOrderDetail>()
        {
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 1 },
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 2 },
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 3 }
        }
    },
    new SalesOrder()
    {
        OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
        OrderDetails = new List<SalesOrderDetail>()
        {
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 1 },
            new SalesOrderDetail() { ItemId = 2 }
        }
    }
};

_context.SalesOrders.AddRange(salesOrders);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Yes, navigation properties are not only helpful when using Include as you retrieve data, but also make saving a lot easier!

Comment: Nice!  I was going to try it myself, but I had to create database stuff first.  This is great to know.